# Why is my function checkUser() undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have created a short script within my signup page which defines the `function checkUser(user)` at line 6.

Now in the bottom end of the code containing the HTML for the sign up form, I have added an inline script of `onBlur='checkUser(this)` to the `<input>` named `'user'`.

However when this object loses focus and the onBlur function is supposed to be triggered, the javascript console states that the `function checkUser` has not been defined. Why is this happening?

My only guess is that the script and the html are in separate strings but I have no idea.

I have attached the full PHP code for signup.php for this example.

```
<?php //signup.php
include_once 'header.php';

echo <<<END_
<script type='text/css'>
function checkUser(user) {
    "use strict";
    if (user.value == '') {
        O('info').innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }

    params = "user=" + user.value;
    request = new ajaxRequest();
    request.open("POST", "checkuser.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    request.onreadystatechance = function() {
        "use strict";
        if (this.readyState == 4)
            if (this.status == 200)
                if (this.responseText != null)
                    O('info').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    request.send(params);
}
</script>$n
<div class='main'><h3>Please enter your details to sign up</h3>
END_;
$salt = "user";
$error = $user = $pass = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) destroySession();

if (isset($_POST['user']) &&
    isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
    $token = md5($salt, $pass);

    if ($user == "" || $pass == "") {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered.</br></br>";
    } else {
        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='$user'"))) {
            $error = "That username already exists.</br></br>";
        } else {
            queryMysql("INSERT INTO members VALUE('$user', '$token')");
            die ("<h4>Account created</h4>Please Log in.</br></br>");
        }
    }
}

echo <<<END_
<form method='post' action='signup.php'>$error
<span class='fieldname'>Username</span>
<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value'$user' onBlur='checkUser(this)'/><span id='info'></span></br>
<span class='fieldname'>Password</span>
<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='pass' value='$pass'/></br>
<span class='fieldname'>&nbsp;</span>
<input type='submit' value='Sign up' />
</form></div></br></body></html>
END_;
?>
```

Comment: Um, `<script type="text/css">`? Try getting rid of the `type` attribute, or at least change it to `"text/javascript"` or `"application/javascript"`.

Comment: Sidenote: Change `VALUE` to `VALUES` but that's a typo, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I have a session_start(); loaded from the include 'header.php'

as for the VALUE, are you positive it is values instead? And are you talking about inside the checkUser function?

Comment: From my beginnings in learning SQL, I'd say so. As per [`the SQL manual`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) - Yet if you're using some type of framework which replaces VALUE for VALUES? @MunkyMead

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh I see now, I didn't realise you were referring to the query. Somehow it still managed to work all this time.

Comment: Really? That's most bizarre. @MunkyMead

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I thought so too. If you're up for it I've just posted another question. I'm clueless on this one, I know it's something simple too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the tag

```
<script type='text/css'>
```

by

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

Comment: Better yet, just get rid of the `type` attribute.

Comment: lol cheers I noticed after my question had been posted, my editor shows all strings in a bright orange. Will set as answer when the timer finishes

Answer (score 0):

I have found it, apologies. I have noticed the script type is set to text/css
It's so difficult to tell when writing in a string.